# Anorm is just locking on executeUpdate

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.1, anorm

I have a very simple Play 2.1 Scala project. As in, this is the only code in it so far. I have a task which I am running with an `Akka.system.scheduler`. I have some code to select from the database (currently the standard test H2 instance) and I'm following the [documentation example](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAnorm) almost exactly.

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  Logger.info("2")
  var x = SQL("insert into x (a, b, c) values ({a, b, c})").on(
    'a -> a,
    'b -> b,
    'c -> c
  )
  Logger.info("2.5")
  x.executeUpdate()
  Logger.info("3")
```

It never gets past 2.5. I haven't got any other database operations happening (except for evolutions).

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your link, shouldn't your SQL statement look like:

```
 var x = SQL("insert into x (a, b, c) values ({a}, {b}, {c})").on(
    "a" -> a,
    "b" -> b,
    "c" -> c
  )
```

In the question the values don't have individual braces: `{a, b, c}`.

Comment: Interesting. The documentation I was working from used `'symbol`s (which surely should yield the equivalent string?). It didn't occur to me to try strings.

Comment: Here is the documentation that shows using symbols: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTodoList (search for 'insert into').

Comment: No different with real strings, I'm afraid.

Comment: What about the separated values? I don't think it can properly use {a,b,c}

Comment: I think I am doing exactly what the documentation says (I could be wrong). http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAnorm

Comment: You're not separating your values. You have ({a, b, c}), when it should be ({a}, {b}, {c}).

Comment: (I have added my mistake to your answer for clarity).